# Controller logic for referenced_in and references_many in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have been trying to use mongoid with the referenced_in and references_many associations. I have two models, User and Question. A question can have one author, but a user can be an author to multiple questions. The below snippet shows the models' structure.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  references_many :questions, :inverse_of => :poster, :dependent => :delete
end 

class Question
  include Mongoid::Document
  referenced_in :poster, :class_name => "User"
end
```

Now, my QuestionController#new is as follows

```
def create
  @question = Question.new(params[:question])
  @question.poster = current_user

  if @question.save
    current_user.questions <<= @question
    current_user.update_attributes(:questions => current_user.questions)
  end
end
```

The question.poster field is correctly populated, but the user.questions array is not populated. What would be the correct controller logic for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model looks good. You don't need to do all that work in your controller though. It should look something like this:

```
def create
  @question = current_user.questions.build(params[:question])

  if @question.save
    #redirect logic goes here
  end
end
```

You don't need to explicitly add the question to the user's question array.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for the reply. I tried that, but `User.first.questions` still returns `nil`. Though the `poster_id` field reflects in the question's values, there is no corresponding field in the user. How can I access the user's question array?

Comment: It should be returning a criteria object when you call that. What version of mongoid are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.0.0.rc.6. I get `[]` when I do `User.last.questions` (after I try create a new question for the last user through the application).

Comment: Are you sure the question is valid? A validation error would prevent it from persisting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried in the following way

```
def create
  @question = Question.new(params[:question])

  if @question.valid?
    current_user.questions << @question

  end
end
```

`<<` is overwritten by mongoid and it save both `current_user` and `@question` at once.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it did not work. Even after doing that, the questions array is still empty.
`irb(main):009:0> User.last.questions`
`=> []`